# pdflscape fails to rotate page containing only a float

Tags: floats, rotating, landscape, pdflscape

I'm using `pdflscape` to place some landscape pages in a long portrait document, because it contains some very wide floats.

However, when a float is so big that it needs its own page, it is no longer rotated correctly:

The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{landscape}
\lipsum[5-6]

\begin{figure}
\lipsum[7-8]
\caption{Some text, rotated correctly.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\lipsum[9-12]
\caption{Some more text, wrong side up.}
\end{figure}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Produces that output:

[image: PDF output]

How can I correctly rotate float-only pages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Package `pdflscape` is just a wrapper for package `lscape`. It sets the `/Rotate` entry in the PDF page data structure. Thus the question shows the correct orientation of the paper, pages 2 and 3 are in landscape.

However the contents of the third page is not shown correctly. Package `lscape` hooks into macros of the output routine that constructs the page contents and rotates the output box. But it misses a case:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% smaller images for answer
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\rule{5mm}{50mm}\hfill\rule{5mm}{50mm}
\begin{figure}
\rule{5mm}{90mm}\hfill\rule{5mm}{90mm}
\caption{Some text, not rotated, wrong footer}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Page 1:

> [image: Page 1]

Page 2:

> [image: Page 2]

Package `lscape` hooks into

- `\@makecol`: normal page
- `\@makefcolumn`: float page. It calls `\@tryfcolumn` inside a group
  and the actual work is done in macro `\@vtryfc`.

But this misses a case. The output routine starts with:

```
\output {%
  \let \par \@@par
  \ifnum \outputpenalty<-\@M
    \@specialoutput
  \else
    \@makecol
    \@opcol
    \@startcolumn
    \@whilesw \if@fcolmade \fi
      {%
       \@opcol\@startcolumn}%
  \fi
```

`\@makecol` constructs the first page, it is caught by package `lscape` and rotated. `\@opcol` outputs the page. Then `\@startcolumn` is called. It also invokes `\@tryfcolumn`, but not `\@makefcolumn`. Thus an output page is constructed, but not detected by package `lscape`. (The same happens to `\@startdblcolumn` that also invokes `\@tryfcolumn`, but I have not tested, whether twocolumn stuff works at all.)

Fix suggestion (after package `lscape` or `pdflscape`):

```
\makeatletter
\let\LS@vtryfc\@vtryfc
\g@addto@macro\landscape{%
  \def\@vtryfc#1{%
    \LS@vtryfc{#1}%
    \LS@rot
  }%
}   
\makeatother
```

Then the second page of the example becomes:

> [image: Page 2, corrected]

And the last page of the question is also correct:

> [image: Last page of question, corrected]