# Float positioning with pdflscape package

Tags: floats, positioning, landscape, pdflscape

I'm using the [pdflscape package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape) to create a document with several sections that need to be in landscape. I am seeing strange behavior with figure floats.

I would like to use `htp` for figure positioning, but I'm noticing that:

1. At a certain size (I'm guessing where the float algorithm chooses `p`), the float gets rotated in a strange location when it probably should fit fine in the page.

   [image]
2. If we force `t!`, the float seems to fit fine, but gets placed on its own page at the end of the section (like I would expect `p` to do).

   [image]

I want the appearance of #2 (landscaped image), but in the location of #1 (on the next page in the text). Is this possible?

## Example code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\section{Initial content}

\blindtext[2]


\begin{landscape}

\section{Landscape content}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{example-image}
\caption{The Universe}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[5]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.3]{example-image}
\caption{The Universe}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[4]

\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.3]{example-image}
\caption{The Universe}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[4]

\blindtext[4]

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you should better use example-image instead of your picture as it sizes change if you embed it like this.

Comment: Can you clarify? I included the example image at the bottom of my post. Are you saying Stack Exchange resizes it?

Comment: well download the image and try yourself: if is much too large.

Comment: I really have no idea what you're getting at. I downloaded the file and it is the exact same image I am using in my example (except that SE renames it). The original file came from Overleaf. You can see the example here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/jzbqywccfcdj

Comment: really? that is curious, I get an image that is much too large. I had to use a scale factor from around 1 to get it on the page. In any case: [ht!] should work if the image is small enough, you can also set locally `\textfloatsep= 0pt` to avoid that it is added to the float size.

Comment: It is still easier for people to test if you use `example-image` (and adjust the scaling if necessary so the problem shows)

Comment: Ahh...now I understand what you're getting at. Until you formatted "`example-image`", I thought you were talking vaguely about an example image (e.g., the one I provided). I didn't know this feature existed. Apologies for my lack of awareness. I've updated my example image to be "`example-image`". Here's a helpful link in case anyone else has the same confusion: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231741/25541

Comment: I realized that my question was already answered here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127546/25541. I flagged my questions as a duplicate.